# How to parse and modify LUA file when it contains INCLUDE definition with C++?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to parse and modify **LUA** files which relate to cartographer by C++. I'm a newbie in LUA, can't handle the lua file with complicate structures. Here's the example of the file:

```
//test.lua

include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"

options = {
    map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
    trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
    map_frame = "map",
    tracking_fame = "base_link",
    published_frame = "base_link",
    ...
    submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
    ...
}

--MAP_BUILDER
MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_3d = true
MAP_BUILDER.num_background_threads = 7

--POSE_GRAPH
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 640
...

--TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D.max_range = 50.
...

return options
```

and next,

```
//map_builder.lua

include "pose_graph.lua"

MAP_BUILDER = {
    use_trajectory_builder_2d = false,
    use_trajectory_builder_3d = false,
    num_background_threads = 4,
    pose_graph = POSE_GRAPH,
    ...
}
```

pose_graph.lua:

```
//pose_graph.lua

POSE_GRAPH = {
    optimize_every_n_nodes = 20,
    constraint_builder = {
        smapling_ratio = 0.03,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

trajectory_builder.lua:

```
//trajectory_builder.lua

include "trajectory_builder_2d.lua"
include "trajectory_builder_3d.lua"

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER = {
    trajectory_builder_2d = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D,
    trajectory_builder_3d = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D,
    collate_fixed_frame = true,
    ...
}
```

trajectory_builder_2d.lua:

```
//trajectory_builder_2d.lua

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D = {
    ...
}
```

trjectory_builder_3d.lua:

```
//trajectory_builder_3d.lua

MAX_3D_RANGE = 100.
...
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D = {
    ...
}
```

And finally, this is my test code:

---

I had *re-edit* my code like this, it seems like I should handle **MAP_BUILDER** etc. in `luaInclude()` before loading the file. And so, what's the correct way to handle them before load the `test.lua` file?

```
int luaInclude(lua_State *L) {
    printf("include file: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    // get include lua file name and handle it here
    // how to handle MAP_BUILDER etc.? 
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_register(L, "include", luaInclude);

    if(luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua")) {
        printf("read file failed: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "options");
    int size = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_pushnil(L);

    // here to do sth. 
    // like modify "submap_publish_period_sec" from 0.3 to 0.6

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

But, I got error:

```
test.lua: attempt to index global 'MAP_BUILDER'(a nil value)!
```

So, how to handle something like "**MAP_BUILDER**"、"**POSE_GRAPH**" and "**TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D**" in `test.lua`? Help!

Comment: You should run a preprocessor (to execute `#include` directives) before invoking `luaL_dofile`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Did you mean I should handle the global **MAP_BUILDER** in function `luaInclude` ?

Comment: Why do you need  `luaInclude()` if you never invoke it in your code?  Preprocessor must insert some Lua files into another files according to `#include` directives.

Comment: Just a wild guess: try to remove `#` in every `#include`.

Comment: `#include "foo"` is interpreted as `#(include "foo")` by the way, so the `#` would be causing a different error than "attempt to index nil"

Comment: The posted code shoud work if you just define "include = dofile" before loading it.